# How to print specific pattern with sed

Tags: sed

Need to duplicate the last word in machine pattern

```
hi abd 123
hiabd 2 44
hi 12 233
```

Output should be:

```
hi abd 123 123 123
hiabd 2 44 44 44
```

Here's what I tried:

```
sed  '/abd/!d' F1
```

But it's not duplicating the last word.
I know I can do something with backtracking but its misunderstood, please assist I can use only sed command.

Comment: "Duplicate on lines that don't contain `abd`", I take it? Not based on the description, but based on the desired output and your attempt. And with "duplicate", you mean "duplicate twice"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -n '/abd/ {s/\( [^ ]\+\)$/&\1\1/p}' file
```

or

```
sed -nE '/abd/{ s/( [^ ]+)$/&\1\1/p}' file
```

Output:

```
hi abd 123 123 123
hiabd 2 44 44 44
```

---

See: [Back-references and Subexpressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Back_002dreferences-and-Subexpressions.html)

Comment: If there is a single command after the address, no braces are necessary. This would not be hard to generalize to (some) non-GNU `sed` dialects.

Comment: if I have one word in line in the file he won't print him, why?

Comment: @AvihuH Because this regex assumes at least one space. In other words, at least two words.

Comment: Thank you, what do I need to to in order the he’ll print the word even if it’s one word in sentence ?

Comment: @AvihuH: I recommend to start a new question.

Answer (score 1):

In case you need an `awk` solution, following may also help you in same too.

```
awk '/abd/{print $0,$NF,$NF}'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
hi abd 123 123 123
hiabd 2 44 44 44
```

Answer (score 0):

For variety, using only [`bash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html):

```
while IFS= read -r line; do 
    [[ $line =~ abd ]] && echo "$line ${line##* } ${line##* }"
done < file
```

You can choose a different [character set](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching) as a word delimiter, for example:

```
#space and tab are delimiters
${line##*[[:blank:]]}

#character 'a' and 'c' are delimiters
${line##*[ac]}
```

Also, you don't even need the binary operator `=~`. `[[ $line = *abd* ]]` will suffice. Note that using `bash` is noticeably slower than the `awk` and `sed` solutions here.